# How to install sample data after the installation is already done?

Tags: installation

I made a wrong choice in the configuration of Joomla.

I wanted to have Default English (GB) Sample Data but I gave the first choice.

enter image description here

I need the protostar template as it is in “Default English (GB) Sample Data” version and not as the default. 
[image]

I have to work with the project I created and I can’t create a new one in order to set the right choice. What I tried is to take the version of protostar template from the version of “Default English (GB) Sample Data” an make it a zip and upload it as a new extension-template.

But it gives me the message

```
   Warning
   Template Install: There is already a Template using the named directory: Install. Are you trying to install the same template again?
```

What can I do in order to upload the version I want?

Comment: In both cases the template is the same. What you are talking about here is the data. So, what you are trying to do?

Comment: I try to take the sql files from zip file of install joomla under installation/sql/prostgres. I tried to insert them into the database for joomla I have but I could not upload the files using the phpmyadmin. Any suggestions? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Best practice is do not install sample data into a project that will go live.  Use a development server to load sample data.  You do not need sample data to configure the template as required, you can do this with your own content. Use the development install as a reference for 'howto'

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments already, the Protostar template is installed perfectly fine in your installation.

The default sample data would only add some modules to the page. But this is unrelated to the template itself.

It looks like this without sample data
[image: Without Sample Data]

and this is with the default sample data
[image: Default Sample Data]

The difference is that with the sample data you have

- The "Main Menu" module on `position-1` (the "Home" button)
- An custom HTML module showing a picture on `position-3`
- The "Popular Tags" and "Latest Articles" modules on `position-7` (right sidebar)
- An article "Getting Started" assigned to the homepage